# USB device doesn't work since I reinstall ubuntu

Tags: boot, usb

My computer was dual boot Ubuntu and Windows and it crashed. Since then the usb device doesn't work even during boot. I reinstalled Ubuntu on my hardrive with another computer because I haven't any CD drives. I don't want to have dual boot anymore.
The command lsusb doesn't show any result.
thanks in advance

Comment: Which USB device? Can you please elaborate your question a little more?

Comment: I tried with usb key and usb mouse. I also tried with my phone, and it's just charging. It's a laptop and the keyboard and the touch pad work.